# AJAX call working but page not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I am using python flask, I want the status of the button to change from "like" to liked when a user clicks it. I get no console errors, XHR loads perfectly. If I click the button and reload the page manually the status of the button changes, but I will like to do the reload with Ajax. Here is my code, thanks in advance. 
The backend returns a JSON object with jsonify.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-pill btn-warning btn-xs" id="async_like">
<span class="icon icon-thumbs-up"></span> Like
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('button#async_like').click(function () {

  $.ajax({
    url :"{{ url_for('.like_post', id=post.id) }}",
    type : 'POST',
    success : function (resp) {
        $('#async_like').append(resp);
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Is requirement for `"#async_like"` selector HTML to remain the same after reloading the `document`?

Comment: please show the value of `resp`

Comment: Don't use `.append()`, that will add the new content from `resp` after the existing button content. Assuming you want to replace the existing button content use `.html()` instead.

Comment: See [Global Variable usage on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/)

Comment: @guest271314 I am not sure I totally understand your question, this is my attempt answering. Yes I should remain the same and only affect the post whose button is clicked

Comment: i think your element button should have close tag </button>.

Comment: do you have multiple buttons with `id="async_like"` ?

Comment: @Jaromanda X no I do not

Comment: I misunderstood a comment on that case

Comment: @aharding378 _"If I click the button and reload the page manually the status of the button changes"_ Is expected result for HTML set following `$.ajax()` call to remain rendered when `window` is reloaded?

Comment: guest271314 yes, that's what I am expecting. I have replaced .append with .html() but getting the same result

Comment: Have you read linked Question and answers?

Comment: @guest271314 yes but I am not sure how to apply that to my code, it seems to be more complex. Any tips?

Comment: The "tips" are at the linked Question and Answers. You can use several different approaches to achieve requirement, including `window.history` or query string parameters.

Comment: @ nnnnnn I have changed .append to .html but getting the same result

Comment: The code will continue to get the same result. An HTML `document` does not store the content of the `document` which is adjusted by user at browser. The reload request is for the HTML stored at server. One option is to use `window` object to store data before reload and access the stored data after reload.

Comment: @guest271314 I am looking at the linked question but I am honestly confused by it. I am a beginner with JS

Comment: You could consider taking the time to read the question and answers.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach could be to use query string parameter when reloading HTML document. At `load` event of `window` check if `location.search` is not an empty string, or is a specific key, value pair, if the condition is true, set the HTML using the query string key and value.

```
$.ajax()
.then(resp => {
  $("#async_like").html(resp);
  location.href = location.href + "?button=" + resp
})
```

At `.ready()` alias `jQuery()` at each HTML `document` check if the query string exists to set HTML of an element

```
$(() => {
  if (location.search) {
    let [prop] = [...new URLSearchParams(location.search).values()];
    if (prop === "clicked") {
      $("#element").html(prop);
    }
  }
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/3VQVSevHFvSE8SYcNEvU?p=preview